# Sass and node-sass not working with react app

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I am trying to use Sass in my react app.

I am aware node-sass is now deprecated and only version 4 and below of node-sass work with node. However, even when I install node-sass@4.14.1 npm doesn't allow me to install saying there is an error tar@2.2.2

So i install normal sass and normal sass asks me to install node-sass ...

So i go around in circles like a headless chicken. Neither node-sass or normal sass working for me.

Comment: What is normal sass? You want to install dart sass with npm or yarm. Dart sass is the recommended version. https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

Comment: Yes normal sass is dart sass. I installed but had issues on a project. I updated tar to version 6 and it still wouldn't work. Then I did it on a new project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes normal sass is dart sass. I installed but had issues on a project. I updated tar to version 6 and it still wouldn't work. Then I did it on a new project and it worked.